# How to stream video from Inskam endoscope to PC via Wi-Fi?

Tags: camera, streaming, live-streaming

I have [Inskam Wi-Fi endoscope](http://www.inskam.com/index.php/Product/view/id/761.html).

After launch, it starts Wi-Fi network. To see video stream, you need to connect to network via phone with Inskam application for Android or iOS installed.

But I need to capture a video stream on my PC.

I think that camera turns on the streaming application. My idea is to directly access the streaming resource.

I've tried to access it from my PC via connect to camera Wi-Fi network:

- http://192.168.29.102:8080/
- http://192.168.29.102:8080/?action=stream
- http://192.168.1.1:8080/
- http://192.168.1.1:8080/?action=stream

Connection is failed.

How to capture video stream of camera via PC?

[image: that pc app default preferences on the right]

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to use your PC to play the stream from your [Wi-Fi endoscope](http://www.inskam.com/index.php/Product/view/id/761.html), which only provides iOS/Android app to watch the stream?

Maybe there is another solution: Use iOS or Android to play the stream, then use OBS to capture the screen of your mobile phone(please see tutorial for [iOS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gvztIe4YvHc) or [Android](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iqqlaOEx9j0)), now you could use OBS to stream to anywhere.

It works like this:

```
Wi-Fi      ---Wifi-->  iOS/Android  ---USB-->  OBS
endoscope                                     (PC)
```

OBS is running on your PC and you could record the stream.

If you would to broadcast the stream to internet or other mobile phone, then you could use OBS to publish it to a media server([SRS](https://github.com/ossrs/srs)) or live streaming platform, like bellow:

```
OBS ---RTMP--> SRS/YouTube/Twitch ---> Players                
(PC)                                     (PC/Mobile)
```

It enables multiple users to watch the stream.

Comment: Okay, this is good solution, that will be probably enough. Thank you.

Comment: It's my pleasure.